# Unable to load CURL extension for OpenCart ( php-5.3.13)

Tags: php, wampserver

I'm using Windows 7 64 bit OS.

While installing Opencart I have a error message.

> Warning: CURL extension needs to be loaded for OpenCart to work!

This is what I tried:

wampmanager -> PHP -> PHP Extensions -> php_curl / restart wamp server,

and also tried to install curl form http://www.anindya.com/php-5-4-3-and-php-5-3-13-x64-64-bit-for-windows/ both versions "php-5.4.3-Win32-VC9-x64.zip" and "php-5.3.13-Win32-VC9-x64.zip" .

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Goto your `php.ini` file rather than checking through the WAMP UI, find the extensions list, uncomment & restart. use `phpinfo();` on a `test.php` page, and see the loaded extensions.

Comment: What version of WAMP are you using? Wamp 32bit or WAMP 64bit? The curl extension you download, if that is in fact necessary, should match the WAMP not necessarilly the OS's bits

Answer (score 0):

I´ve never worked with OpenCart but, I usually work with curl and I think you can try to write a simple PHP script outside your OpenCart project to figure out if the problem is with the curl extension installation or with OpenCart.

You can use this simple example to try [CURL Example](http://www.php.net/manual/en/curl.examples-basic.php).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But this is not working for me. i'm just trying to install Opencart.

Comment: But you should check if curl extension is properly installed and working

Answer (score 0):

you need to uncomment the curl extension..

path:-

wamp-->php-->php.ini

and uncomment    extension=php_curl.dll

by default its commented e.g. ;extension=php_curl.dll

remove the semi colon from the starting and save file restart your wamp server
hope it helps you